Jmeter: Need to Pass time delay between the loop not on the each request
My requirement:
I need to run the script with 50 users each having three HTTP requests, and it needs to run in a loop for five times with a pause of two seconds at each loop.
E.g.,
Thread 1: 50 Users
loop:1 
Request 1
Request 2
Request 3 
2 sec delay
loop:2 
Request 1
Request 2
Request 3 
2 sec delay
loop:3
Request 1
Request 2
Request 3 
Like wise, I need to run the loop 10 times with 2 seconds between each iteration.
Can someone please help me on how to achieve this? I have different combinations to perform.
I tried passing a constant timer with 2000 milliseconds, but the delay is applying to all the requests inside the loop. I want the delay only between each loop and not on the request.

JMeter Timers:

Obey JMeter Scoping Rules
Are executed before each Sampler in their scope

So if you need to create a delay between iterations the options are in:

Put the Constant Timer as a child of the 1st Sampler in your Thread Group


Add Flow Control Action Sampler as the last Sampler in your Thread Group



